# I need to decode a image/file passed through ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have read a file from javascript and converted that into 64 bit encoded data
This data has been passed to php.How would I decode it?

Below is my code

```
//function to encode into 64 bit





function handleFileSelect(objEvent) {





var strFiles = objEvent.target.files; // FileList object





//Checking wheter the uploaded file is image or not




for (var i = 0, f; f = strFiles[i]; i++) { 




   var reader = new FileReader();




   // Closure to capture the file information.
   reader.onload = (function(theFile) {




         return function(e) {




            // Render thumbnail.




            strGlobalImageData=e.target.result;alert(strGlobalImageData);





         };




   })(f);




   reader.readAsDataURL(f);




} 




}
```

//I need to pass this data into php via ajax

var app= 'contact.php';

```
$.ajax({




url: app,




async: false,




type:"POST",




data : "file="+strGlobalImageData,




dataType: "jsonp",




contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',





processData:false,




jsonp: "jsoncallback",




success: function(html){




     alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");




},




error: function(){





     alert("Error");




}




});




</script>
```

I am getting this encoded data in php.But I am not able to decode and see its properties

like  'tmp_name','name'......

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Remove all those blank lines, sheesh

Comment: Its showing some error that we cannot leave spaces

Comment: sorry.. the error is leave spaces of 4 between lines